# Black frame for framebox does not show up

Tags: framed

I'm absolutely new in with LaTeX.

I have try a lot of things to have juste a small black border around my box, but when I generate the PDF or when I run, text is here, but there is nothing around.

Maybe I do have a problem with Texmaker?

Sorry, I'm a french speaker. I guess, my English is by far not perfect.

My code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\makebox[\textwidth]{c e n t r a l}
\end{document}
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks you so much.
I'm loosing lot of time to try make it work.

Comment: You have to use `\framebox`, not `\makebox`.

Comment: Or `\fbox` instead of `\framebox`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\makebox` does not draw a frame at all.

Either use `\framebox` or `\fbox` (which does not span to the `\textwidth`, however) or the more sophisticated `tcolorbox` environment.

There are other possibilities with `mdframed` etc.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\parindent=0em
\framebox[\textwidth]{c e n t r a l}

\fbox{c e n t r a l}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,sharp corners,colback=white,halign=center]
  c e n t r a l
\end{tcolorbox}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, impessing reactivity thanks you so much. Actually, I tried and it works. But on my  full report, i have this package '%\usepackage[dvips,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}' and apparently when I activate this, the black line around the text disapear. Maybe you have an idea why? thanks you so much.

Comment: @SimonSays: That's the cause why you should always post a working example ;-) Remove the `xcdraw` option (it's a guess only, however)

Comment: Yes, you're right, but I had a list of package and mess long like the bible. But you're right. I deleted dvips, and actually it works. Thanks you so much.

Comment: @SimonSays: I am wondering why you're using the `dvips` at all nowadays.